# Laravel 5.4 route wildcards

Tags: laravel, routes, wildcard

I was wondering how to create URL's in Laravel, without any prefix.

For Example:

How to transform following URL:

```
http://www.example.com/posts/some-post
```

To this URL:

```
http://www.example.com/some-post
```

I know this can be done as:

```
Route::any('/{slug}', function($slug) {
    $page = App\Models\Page::firstByAttributes(['slug' => $slug]);
    if($page) {
      return Redirect::action('pagesController@find', array($page));
   }
})->where('slug', '.*');
```

But for above code I've to maintain all unique slugs for each URL.

Any other way to do this right?

Thanks.

Comment: How about `Route::get('{slug}', 'pagesController@find');`? Can you show all your routes?

Comment: Do you have to do it in Laravel, why not with Apache/nginx redirects?

Comment: @devk I've already posted same code. Problem is I've to keep record for each slug & calling controller.

Comment: @Don'tPanic I am not sure if its possible to show http://www.example.com/posts/some-post to http://www.example.com/some-post using .htaccess.

Comment: Sure you can - I've added an answer showing how.

Comment: @ImranAli did using .htaccess work?  Or did you want to do this in Laravel?

Comment: @Don'tPanic thanks for .htaccess solution but I am looking for Laravel solution.

Comment: @ImranAli OK, I've added a Laravel option.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it with Laravel:

**Routes**

```
Route::get('posts/{slug}', function($slug) {
    // Does a 302 redirect, and the route below will handle it
    return redirect($slug);
});
Route::get('{slug}', 'pagesController@find');
```

**Controller**

```
public function find($slug) {
    $page = App\Models\Page::where('slug', $slug);
    // ... your code
    // ... 
    // return view('something', ['page' => $page]);
}
```

Comment: This is very similar to my solution posted in question. Actually I wanted to call controller based on url slug. i.e http://www.example.com/{slug}. Right now I am using code posted in my question & its working fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The redirection you describe can be easily done with an Apache rewrite rule, before you hit the application layer, which should be much more efficient.  Eg, assuming Apache is set up to allow redirects from .htaccess, the following should be enough:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^posts/(.*) /$1 [R=301, L]
```

The `R=301` indicates the redirect should happen with a `301` http response code, which will preserve your page rank etc.